# Why mongoDB is used in the MEAN stack

Tags: mongodb

I'm fixing the usability/documentation for the mean stack. I'm starting with Mean.JS. Can someone give me the salient reasons why the authors of the MEAN stack use MongoDB as the database? There are other databases to choose, but MongoDB is used for some reason.

I realize there are questions already covering databases, but I'm wondering specifically why it was used in the MEAN stack scenario.

Comment: Um, you need an 'M' to spell MEAN?

Comment: lol. I think I'm going to say it's good for scaling. I only need one sentence describing it.

Comment: Honestly, the pure javascript stack is more convincing than scalability in Mongo.

Comment: True. Here's what I said: 

"Database designed for scaling.
Learn more about MongoDB."

And then MongoDB links to the manual. Should I put javascript in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It think the primary reason is that MongoDB uses the same language Javascript (ECMA Script) for methods and functions API, rather than a separate language (like SQL).  Thus MongoDB is a good no SQL database option, and it works much more efficiently as a database for the rest of the stack.

As others have pointed out, there are many other reasons, like that it is the most popular NoSQL database at this point.  It has a decent shell and you can write Javascript in it.  It is Open Source and well documented.

It is also really easy to setup, and scales fairly well, although not as good as some other NoSQL databases.

It also uses BSON, which is similar to JSON, which is similar to a Javascript object.  So it is just plain easy to learn and easy to use this particular database with the rest of a Javascript stack.

Answer (score 2):

There's some pretty good reasons here: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/49262866911/the-mean-stack-mongodb-expressjs-angularjs-and

Comment: Please include examples from the given link.

Answer (score 0):

A Glimpse Into Four Key Components - How MEAN Stack Adds New Dimensions To New-Age Web Applications
All four components of MEAN Stack are popular in the app development space. It offers a platform that enables an effortless development work process. Let’s know about every component and its unique features.

MongoDB – Independent database framework
For any web app building, data storage and management are essential. MongoDB is a popular database with NoSQL document to allow this purpose. The primary use case of this framework is to enable data storage and management of every web application development.**[(Read More)](https://www.bytestechnolab.com/blog/the-wonders-of-mean-stack/)**